# UAC prompt for Runddll32

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

Whenever I run an application that needs rundll32.exe I am prompted with a UAC prompt for Rundll32. See the below image, where the blacked out part is the path to the application I am trying to run.

[image: UAC prompt]

The application itself if a C# ClickOnce one that lives on the server and has not been updated. This prompt never used to show up on Windows 10 before.

If it helps I am running Windows 10 Enterprise Edition, Version 1709 and OS Build 16299.125.

How can I stop this from showing?

Comment: Why is your installation out of date, by at least, 6 months?

Comment: @Ramhound This is my PC at work, it gets updated when it gets updated I have no control over that. I thought it was up to date but it must not be. However, this problem has only shown up in the past couple of weeks.

Comment: You failed to provide that information.  Have you contacted the only person who can solve this problem your domain Administrator?  This prompt would happen if the certificate that signed the application wasn’t trusted.

Comment: @Ramhound Well I thought my version was up to date so I didn't think it was necessary. However, as the problem has only shown up recently and my version is out of date I assume this isn't a problem with the version I have installed.

Comment: Your build likely has nothing to do with the problem, doesn’t chnage the fact, your system is 4 months out of date.  Additionally, if this is a certificate problem, only your system administrator can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The windows host process is of higher permission and we can do little about it.
You can try these methods:

Run sfc /scannow in cmd as administrator.

Make sure UAC settings are not on the top notch.

If you have backed up your registry before, you can restore the registry from back up.
https://www.sysnative.com/forums/windows-7-windows-vista-tutorials/3901-manually-restore-registry-its-backup-windows-windows-7-vista.html

If nothing helps, a repair installation will fix it.